# Is there a right or wrong approach to choosing the right synonym for a Product Category?

Tags: seo, keywords, search-results, categories

Let's say I am looking to sell Curtains, Mirrors and Clocks for example.  As such, I would like to create a new Parent Product Category to house these products.

The two that would instantly come to mind, would be:

1. Home Decor
2. Home Furnishings

As part of some preliminary research, I searched for both of these Keywords.  In doing so, I saw that Google emboldened both 'Home Decor' and 'Home Furnishings', for both `Home Decor` and `Home Furnishings` search queries.  For example:

[image]

First of all, would this embolden, be a clear indication that Google sees such Keywords as being synonymous with the search query?  How far does this go?  Is it just for the purpose of the search user or would this be 'confirmation' that Google would use such emboldened synonyms within their algorithms?

Keeping to this example, is it fair to say that either `Home Decor` or `Home Furnishings` could be used?  Is there a right or wrong way to making the right decision here or is it a case of it being a Judgement call.

The Judgement call entailing considerations, such as:

- Search Volume;
- Keyword competition level.

Say a website opted to choose `Home Decor` but then ended up gaining a lot of Back links, with the Anchor Text `Home Furnishings`, would this help boost the rankings for `Home Decor` search queries (due to them being synonymous) or would this only boost the rankings for `Home Furnishings` search queries?

Comment: It is a mistake to take anything away from the bold terms in the SERPs snippets. This is just a last step in creating the SERPs. It does give some clues of course, but please do not take this as evidence of keywords and how search engines handle keywords. The fact of the matter is there are too many steps and processes between the search query and the results to make any assumptions at all. Reverse engineering the SERPs is a fools game! You do not have to worry about synonyms. This is handled using LSI. Use the language your users will use.

Comment: @closetnoc ... Thanks for this.  Referring to the example of `Home Decor` and `Home Furnishings`, what would be a typical thought process on deciding which one to use as the Parent Category title?  Is it a case of just looking at their competitive levels or is it a case of it not mattering, due to them both being synonymous with each other?

Comment: For me, it is a matter of what your audience uses. Otherwise, it should not matter. For example, in the U.S. we say trunk lid or hood and in the U.K. they say boot or bonnet when referring to a car. If you want to know which is used more simply do a search for both in quotes and check the results count. Also, check out what the big boys use. Sometimes this is a good indication, sometimes it is not. The big boys spend a lot of money making it easier for you to gain from their work. I like to cheat! Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc:  *check the results count* ... Would it be a fair assumption that the amount of results would positively correlate to the success of the Keyword?  The more results, for the Keyword, typically the higher its conversion so to speak?

Comment: @closetnoc:  In the UK, both `Home Furnishings` and `Home Decor` are used interchangeably.  `Home Decor` generating the greater search volume and search results.  In these instances, would it be a fair assumption to say that `Home Decor` is likely to carry to greater conversions; based on its greater search results?

Comment: I am not sure about conversion, but it seems a reasonable assumption. I like tradition and convention. If more sites use home decor, then so be it. Rock and roll! Mostly, I do not think it makes a difference, but why not hedge you bets? Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc:  As a closing question, say a site went with `Home Decor` but would also want to rank for `Home Furnishings`, would it be a case of ensuring there are `Home Furnishing` references as well as ensuring that the Back links are a mix of `Home Decor` and `Home Furnishings` Anchor Texts?  Just concerned once a Product Category title has been assigned, it will limit rankings for associated Synonyms.

Comment: One of the most important things I can say to you is... Pages rank, not keywords! No one can make a page rank for any keyword. Why? Because there is no such mechanism. Does not exist. How a page performs for any particular search is search intent relevency gauged upon semantic scoring. After that, other factors come into play such as PR, SERP performance, etc. In your case, you, again, don't need to brute force a behavior out of a search engine when it will do what you want naturally.